# .htaccess rewrite domain.com/en/multisite to domain.com/multisite/en

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, qtranslate-x

I'm using **multisite WordPress** and **qTranslateX plugin**. My default website is in Bahasa and my second language is English. When I use custom link in mode language English like **mydomain.com/multisite**, it always added by "en" after mydomain.com, it will be **mydomain.com/en/multisite**. That link always return 404 because there is no page.

I want to use .htaccess to rewrite URL form mydomain.com/en/multisite to mydomain.com/multisite/en .

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can't achieve that with mod_rewrite alone as far as I know.
Wordpress will look at the REQUEST_URI to figure out what to show, and that one won't be overwritten (and `[E=REQUEST_URI:...]` will make it `$_SERVER["REDIRECT_REDIRECT_REQUEST_URI"]`).

If mod_proxy is installed as well, you could do something like this:

`RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^en/([^/]+)(/?.*)$ /$1/en$2 [P,L]`

It will proxy the request internally on the same host and server.
Requesting http://example.org/en/test will look to wordpress as if http://example.org/test/en was requested.

Give it a try. If mod_proxy isn't installed, it won't work (and render a 404 for the URL), but it won't break your site, so it's pretty safe to experiment with.

Comment: ya, it's return 404, whereas I had install mod_proxy and set to enable.